# I'm new to OOP, and am struggling with a basic inheritance error: Expected class name before '{' token

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to OOP, and am trying to figure my way through inheritance. I have read multiple other posts on here about people who ran into the same issues. From what I could tell many of their issues came from the way their classes were inherited. I thought I had all my ducks in a row, but the compiler keeps throwing me errors. The examples that I have found and read through in the book I'm using (Absolute C++, 6th edition), hasn't covered errors like this yet.  I included all the .cpp, and .h files. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be gratefully appreciated.

point.h

```
#ifndef The_points_H
#define The_points_H


#include <iostream>


class Point{

    public:

        Point(int Xval, int Yval);
        Point();
        int getX() const;
        int getY() const; 
        void setX(int Xval);
        void setY(int Yval);
         

    private:

        int x;
        int y;


};



#endif
```

point.cpp

```
#include "point.h"


Point::Point(int Xval, int Yval): x(Xval), y(Yval) {}
Point::Point(): x(0), y(0) {}


int Point::getX() const {

    return x;
}

int Point::getY() const {

    return y;
}

void Point::setX(int Xval) {

    x = Xval;
}

void Point::setY(int Yval) {

    y = Yval; 
}
```

rectangle.h

```
#ifndef The_rectangle_H
#define The_rectangle_H 


#include "point.h"
#include <iostream>

class Rectangle: public Point {

    public:

        Rectangle(Point(), int h, int w);
        Rectangle();
        Point getTL() const;
        int getHeight() const;
        int getWidth() const; 
        void setHeight(int h);
        void setWidth(int w); 
        Rectangle makeRectangle(Rectangle rect1);
        //friend Rectangle operator %(const Rectangle& rect1, const Rectangle& rect2);

    private:

        Point tL;
        int height;
        int width; 

};

#endif
```

rectangle.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"
#include "rectangle.h"




Rectangle::Rectangle(Point(), int h, int w) : tL(Point()), height(h), width(w) {}
Rectangle::Rectangle() : tL(Point()), height(0), width(0){}


Point Rectangle::getTL() const{

    return tL;
}

int Rectangle::getHeight() const{

    return height;
}

int Rectangle::getWidth() const{

    return width;
}

void Rectangle::setHeight(int h) {

    height = h;
}

void Rectangle::setWidth(int w) {

    width = w;
}

Rectangle Rectangle::makeRectangle(Rectangle rect1) {

    int xPoint1; 
    int yPoint1; 
    int heIgth1; 
    int wIdth1; 

    std::cout << "Enter x1 coordinate: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> xPoint1;
    std::cin.clear();

    std::cout << "Enter y1 coordinate: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> yPoint1;
    std::cin.clear();

    std::cout << "Enter the height1: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> heIgth1;
    std::cin.clear();

    std::cout << "Enter the width1: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> wIdth1;
    std::cin.clear();

    Point p1(xPoint1, yPoint1); 
    Rectangle rect(p1, heIgth1, wIdth1); 


    return rect;
}
```

rect_funcs.h

```
#ifndef Rect_funcs_H
#define Rect_funcs_H

#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"
#include "rectangle.h"


//Rectangle makeRectangle();
void show_Coordinates(Rectangle rect1);
bool operator %(const Rectangle& rect1, const Rectangle& rect2);



#endif
```

rect_funcs.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"
#include "rectangle.h"
#include "rect_funcs.h"


//Function to create anchor point, and get heigth/width values 
/*
Rectangle makeRectangle() {

    int xPoint1; 
    int yPoint1; 
    int heIgth1; 
    int wIdth1; 

    std::cout << "Enter x1 coordinate: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> xPoint1;
    std::cin.clear();

    std::cout << "Enter y1 coordinate: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> yPoint1;
    std::cin.clear();

    std::cout << "Enter the height1: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> heIgth1;
    std::cin.clear();

    std::cout << "Enter the width1: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> wIdth1;
    std::cin.clear();

    Point p1(xPoint1, yPoint1); 
    Rectangle rect(p1, heIgth1, wIdth1); 


    return rect;

}
*/
//Overloading of % operator to check if rectangles overlap or not

bool operator %(const Rectangle& rect1, const Rectangle& rect2){

    Point top_Left1 = rect1.getTL();
    Point bottom_Right1((rect1.getX() + rect1.getWidth()), (rect1.getY() - rect1.getHeight()));

    Point top_Left2 = rect2.getTL();
    Point bottom_Right2((rect2.getX() + rect2.getWidth()), (rect2.getY() - rect2.getHeight()));

    if(top_Left1.getX() == bottom_Right1.getX() || top_Left1.getY() == bottom_Right1.getY() || top_Left2.getX() == bottom_Right2.getX() ||
    top_Left2.getY() == bottom_Right2.getY())

        return false;

    if(top_Left1.getX() >= bottom_Right2.getX() || top_Left2.getX() >= bottom_Right1.getX())

        return false; 

    if(top_Left1.getY() >= bottom_Right2.getY() || top_Left2.getY() >= bottom_Right1.getY())

        return false; 

    return true;
}


void show_Coordinates(Rectangle rect1){


    int x = rect1.getX();
    int y = rect1.getY();
    int heigth = rect1.getHeight();
    int width = rect1.getWidth(); 

    std::cout << "(" << x << "," << y << "), " << "(" << (x + width) << "," << y << "), " 
    << "(" << x << "," << (y - heigth) << "), " << "(" << (x + width) << "," << (y - heigth) << ")"; 
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"
#include "rectangle.h"
#include "rect_funcs.h"

int main() {

    Rectangle rect_1, rect_2;

    rect_1.makeRectangle(rect_1);
    //rect_2 = makeRectangle();

    std::cout << "coordintates of rectangle 1: ";
    show_Coordinates(rect_1);


    return 0;
}
```

A list of the compiler errors

```
g++ -c -g -std=c++11  main.cpp
In file included from point.h:4,
                 from main.cpp:2:
rectangle.h:8:31: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
    8 | class Rectangle: public Point {
      |                               ^
rectangle.h:12:26: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token
   12 |         Rectangle(Point(), int h, int w);
      |                  ~       ^
      |                          )
rectangle.h:14:9: error: ‘Point’ does not name a type
   14 |         Point getTL() const;
      |         ^~~~~
rectangle.h:24:9: error: ‘Point’ does not name a type
   24 |         Point tL;
      |         ^~~~~
make: *** [makefile:15: main.o] Error 1
➜  Sull_hw3 git:(main) ✗
```

Comment: Errors also give the position of the error in your code, can you give us the full error log?

Comment: Just included the errors, my apologies for not doing so originally

Comment: May I ask about `Rectangle(Point(), int h, int w)`? As it stands, the first parameter is a function with no arguments, returning a `Point`, and without a name for the parameter. I doubt that this was your intention. What was your intention?

Comment: Concerning your error... It looks like you did `#include "rectangle.h"` in `point.h` though I cannot see this in your exposed code. In this case, you would have a circular dependency. Are you sure that you exposed the correct code to reproduce your error? Additionally, I'm not sure why the `#include "rectangle.h"` should be necessary in `point.h`.

Comment: It's supposed to be one of the class constructors with Point() creating the top left coordinate of the rectangle.

Comment: I somehow was assuming that. You have two options: 1. Use `Point point` or `const Point& point` instead (and use the base class copy constructor `Point(const Point&)` which is defined implicitly in your case), or 2. just repeat the parameters of base constructor `Point` here, i.e. `int Xval, int Yval` and pass them trough to the base class constructor call.

Comment: Something else, I just noticed. You derived `Rectangle` from `Point` and you added a member `Point tl`. Are you aware that all members of `Point` i.e. `int x; int y;` are members of `Rectangle` as well? (This is how inheritance works.) You prohibited the direct access out of `Rectangle` (the members are `private` in `Point`) but nevertheless they are there. (Not that it is wrong to make member variables `private` - it's considered as good style.)

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But I don't understand how to use a member of another class as a constructor in a new class. 

Looking at it Point tL doesn't make much sense because it is never defined anywhere after the initial declaration. I went in and made the changes you recommended

Comment: I changed the constructor to,
```
    Rectangle::Rectangle(const Point& point, int h, int w) : tL(point), height(h), 
    width(w) {}

```
However that throws a new error, so I am definitely screwing up my constructor.

Comment: Concerning the `Point tL`: I believe this is obsolete. Have a look at your `show_coordinates()`. There you use `getX()` and `getY()` and this is what I would expect. But it means you use the inherited `Point` to store the top left corner of your rectangle. Considering this, `Point tL` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I made a reduced and cleaned up mcve out of your code: [mcve on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c41e84035b8550e)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I really appreciate you for taking the time to help point me in the right direction. It's almost 2 am for me, but I will have this running tomorrow. I will be back with the finished product.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, The completed program. I appreciate the help. 
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cca103d7835f03bc

You'd have to break it down into corresponding .cpp/.h files. But it compiles and runs as expected.